# Filter an object by value from array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object `b` and an array `a`. I would like to filter `b` to only have objects where the `to` values are in `a`. I've tried many ways but I always receive an empty array. For example this case, the final result would be an array with the first and the second object from the array but not the last one.

```js
const a = [
    "dfd302f4-571b-42da-9b35-07d1d9b6e68d",
    "d7099abd-6872-48db-bdd7-ca99e4513586",
    "93272093-5089-40cd-8c3d-2412377e1f32"
  ];

  const b = [
    {
      name: "toto",
      to: [
        "d7099abd-6872-48db-bdd7-ca99e4513586",
        "93272093-5089-40cd-8c3d-2412377e1f32"
      ]
    },
    { name: "tota", to: ["dfd302f4-571b-42da-9b35-07d1d9b6e68d"] },
    { name: "tota", to: ["8418v4rfe484evf48ez64vrfe6zv4r8ezvf4"] }
  ];

  console.log(b.filter(user => a.includes(user.to)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to check array with array (use some and includes)

```js
const a = [
  "dfd302f4-571b-42da-9b35-07d1d9b6e68d",
  "d7099abd-6872-48db-bdd7-ca99e4513586",
  "93272093-5089-40cd-8c3d-2412377e1f32",
];

const b = [
  {
    name: "toto",
    to: [
      "d7099abd-6872-48db-bdd7-ca99e4513586",
      "93272093-5089-40cd-8c3d-2412377e1f32",
    ],
  },
  { name: "tota", to: ["dfd302f4-571b-42da-9b35-07d1d9b6e68d"] },
  { name: "tota", to: ["8418v4rfe484evf48ez64vrfe6zv4r8ezvf4"] },
];

console.log(b.filter(({ to }) => to.some((item) => a.includes(item))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt,

```
console.log(b.filter(user => a.includes(user.to)))
```

fails to work because `user.to` is an array, and `a` does not include any arrays.

You need to use the `every` method to check if all elements of the array in the `to` property are inside `a`:

```js
const a = [
    "dfd302f4-571b-42da-9b35-07d1d9b6e68d",
    "d7099abd-6872-48db-bdd7-ca99e4513586",
    "93272093-5089-40cd-8c3d-2412377e1f32"
  ];

const b = [
  {
    name: "toto",
    to: [
      "d7099abd-6872-48db-bdd7-ca99e4513586",
      "93272093-5089-40cd-8c3d-2412377e1f32"
    ]
  },
  { name: "tota", to: ["dfd302f4-571b-42da-9b35-07d1d9b6e68d"] },
  { name: "tota", to: ["8418v4rfe484evf48ez64vrfe6zv4r8ezvf4"] }
];

 console.log(b.filter(user => user.to.every(str => a.includes(str))));
```

EDIT: you could use `some` instead of `every`, as in @SivaKV's answer. That depends on whether you want an item to be included whose "to" array has some items in `a` and some not ("every" would not include these, but "some" would), which isn't clear from your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.some` or `.every` depending on whether it is sufficient that one or all elements of the `.to` property must be in array `a`.

```js
const a = [
"dfd302f4-571b-42da-9b35-07d1d9b6e68d",
"d7099abd-6872-48db-bdd7-ca99e4513586",
"93272093-5089-40cd-8c3d-2412377e1f32"
  ];
const b = [
{
  name: "toto",
  to: [
    "d7099abd-6872-48db-bdd7-ca99e4513586",
    "93272093-5089-40cd-8c3d-2412377e1f32"
  ]
},
{ name: "tota", to: ["dfd302f4-571b-42da-9b35-07d1d9b6e68d"] },
{ name: "tota", to: ["8418v4rfe484evf48ez64vrfe6zv4r8ezvf4"] }
  ];

  console.log(b.filter(u => u.to.every(e=>a.includes(e))))
```